# invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can't figure out how to rewrite this sql statement to avoid the error below

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 26 Column
>   'StaffMember.StaffMemberId' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

SQL Statement:

```
SELECT (
        SELECT [dbo].[udf_ReadStaffMemberBasic](SM.StaffMemberId)
        FOR XML PATH('StaffMemberSummary'),
            ROOT('Items'),
            TYPE
        ),
    COUNT(SM.StaffMemberId) AS TotalResults,
    CEILING(CAST(COUNT(SM.StaffMemberId) AS DECIMAL) / @PageSize) AS TotalPages
FROM StaffMember SM
INNER JOIN StaffMemberToAdditionalRole AR
    ON SM.StaffMemberId = AR.StaffMemberId
WHERE (
        SM.Firstname LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
        OR SM.Surname LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
        )
    AND (
        @FloorId IS NULL
        OR SM.FloorId = @FloorId
        )
    AND (
        @DirectorateId IS NULL
        OR SM.DirectorateId = @DirectorateId
        )
    AND (
        @AdditionalRoleId IS NULL
        OR AR.AdditionalRoleId = @AdditionalRoleId
        )
ORDER BY SM.StaffMemberId OFFSET @Page * @PageSize ROWS

FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

What I'm trying to do is to return a list of Staff members from a function and pagination data all as XML.

Comment: The error message can't be more clear. You need to add a GROUP BY to your query for SM.StaffMemberId, or wrap the column with MAX.

Comment: Yes you are totally right, sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees. I'm now getting -  the totalPages and Results back for each staff member when I really want one TotalPages and TotalResults value passed back.

Comment: Then, remove the StaffMemberId from `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` which forces such a grouping.